# Usart interrupt registeration

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, usart, rs485

I am using AT32UC series (custom board) for my application and Usart RS485 interrupts are killing me today. 
I have Rx interrupt set up and working. Now trying to add Tx interrupt to be called if data is available to send. 
My problem is that the tx interrupt is never called. After few hours fighting for this I've found something strange.

```
int main()
.....// other initialisations
INTC_init_interrupts();
INTC_register_interrupt(&timerInterrupt, AVR32_TC_IRQ0, AVR32_INTC_INT0);
INTC_register_interrupt(&rs485TxInterrupt, AVR32_USART2_IRQ, AVR32_INTC_INT1);
INTC_register_interrupt(&rs485RxInterrupt, AVR32_USART2_IRQ, AVR32_INTC_INT0);              
Enable_global_interrupt();
```

From above, I get rx interrupt working and if I change the order of INTC rx interrupt with tx interrupt, I get tx interrupt working and no rx interrupt. Function calling each interrupts are also in main. Can someone explain what is wrong with my understanding in implementing interrupts. I've also attached snippets of relevant codes for further reference.

```
static void SendTx(void)
{   
    txLength = 5;
    gpio_set_pin_high(AVR32_PIN_PA10);
    txBuf[0] = ATEAddress;
    AVR32_USART2.THR.txchr = txBuf[0];
    tx_outctr = 1;

    if(peaksRdy_flag == true)
    {
        txBuf[1] = peaks[loop][0];  
        txempty_flag = false;
        AVR32_USART2.ier = AVR32_USART_IER_TXRDY_MASK;
    }
}
__attribute__((__interrupt__)) static void rs485TxInterrupt(void)
{   
    //AVR32_USART2.IDR.txrdy = 1;
    AVR32_USART2.THR.txchr = txBuf[1];
    AVR32_USART2.CR.sttbrk = 1;
    gpio_set_pin_low(AVR32_PIN_PA10);
    gpio_set_pin_low(AVR32_PIN_PA06);
    if(!txempty_flag)
    {   
       //gpio_set_pin_high(AVR32_PIN_PA06);
        //AVR32_USART2.IMR.txrdy;
    }
}

static void readRx(void)
{   
AVR32_USART2.CR.txdis = 1;
AVR32_USART2.ier = AVR32_USART_IER_RXRDY_MASK;
}

__attribute__((__interrupt__)) static void rs485RxInterrupt(void)
{

//AVR32_USART2.IDR.rxrdy = 1;
uint32_t data;
static char RxDatalength = 98;
data = AVR32_USART2.RHR.rxchr;

    if(data & 0x00000100)
    {
        if((data & 0x000000ff) == 0x92) //dsp board address = 0x92
        {

            rxBuf[0] = data;
            addr_flag = true;
            rxInCtr = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            addr_flag = false;
            return;
        }
     }

     else if (addr_flag == true)
     {
         rxBuf[rxInCtr++] = data;
         if(rxInCtr == 2)           // command check
         {
            if(data < 0x80)
            {   
                addr_flag = false;  // reset addr flag
                if(data==0x10)//START
                {

                    start_flag = true;

                }
                else if(data == 0x11) //CANCEL
                {
                    gpio_set_pin_high(AVR32_PIN_PA13);
                    break_flag = true;
                }
            }
            else if(data >= 0x80)

                RxDatalength = 3;
        }

         if ((rxInCtr == RxDatalength) || ((RxDatalength == 98) && (rxInCtr == rxBuf[2]+1)))
         {
            //gpio_set_pin_high (AVR32_PIN_PA16);
            addr_flag = false;
            start_flag = true;
         }
     }
gpio_set_pin_low(AVR32_PIN_PA13);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: regarding this line: 'if(peaksRdy_flag == true)'  never compare to 'true'.   the line could be written as: 'if(peaksRdy_flag)' or as: 'if(peaksRdy_flag != false)'  Because 'true' can be anything (and on several compilers it is defined as 2, but others define it as 1 and others define it as !false.)

Comment: the interrupt handler function needs to clear the appropriate 'interrupt pending' flag.  Otherwise, the interrupt will keep re-occurring, even though there is no new interrupt event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering two different routines for the same interrupt (`AVR32_USART2_IRQ`), so that the second registration just overwrites the first one.

Notice that there's only *one* IRQ/ISR for both RX and TX in the AT32UC and you'll have to determine which one occurred yourself in your ISR, see e.g. http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/how-distinguish-usart-interrupts-txrdy-rxrdy.

Comment: So it means I register one interrupt say USART interrupt, and from there I distinguish if its tx or rx interrupt that I wish to call? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: And should I not be registering both rx and tx interrupt in the main?? If so, how does tx and rx interrupts get called by reading channel status register to distinguish between tx and rx but they are not registered in INTC??

Comment: "it means I register one interrupt say USART interrupt, and from there..." - Yes, that's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: You should be registering exectly *one* interrupt handler routine for the `AVR32_USART2_IRQ`. In that interrupt handler routine, your code reads the channel status and decides if it has to read or write data.